# How to apply Novikov Theorem in Deriving Fokker-Planck Equation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am looking at this paper [Smoluchowski diffusion equation for active Brownian swimmers](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.91.052150), in which they describe using something called Novikov's theorem to take correlations between a random force and a delta function that describes density. I have tried reading the references they provide, but the math is just beyond me. Has anyone encountered this or do they have a clear explanation?

From the paper:

Given a stochastic brownian processes $\beta(t)$, described by a vanishing average $<\beta(t)> = 0$ and correlation $<\beta(t)\beta(s)> =2\gamma\delta(t-s)$

The functional of that process $F[\beta(t)]$ has the property

$$
<F[\beta(t)]\beta(t)> = \gamma<\frac{\tilde{\delta}F[\beta(t)]}{\tilde{\delta}\beta(t)}>
$$
Where the right hand side is the variational derivative.

They then use that theorem to get this... (moving from equations 2 to 3)

$$
-\nabla\cdot<\xi(t)\delta(x-x(t))\delta(\varphi-\varphi(t)> = D_B\nabla^2P(x,\varphi,t)
$$

Comment: Let's forget about the process aspect here for now and just look at a Gaussian random variable $\beta$ (of zero mean, $\sigma^2$ variance), and a function $f(\beta)$:

$$\langle f(\beta) \beta \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) x \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x) \sigma^2 \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \mathrm{d}x = \sigma^2\left\langle \frac{\mathrm{d} f(\beta)}{\mathrm{d} \beta} \right\rangle$$

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense, do you have any knowledge on how I would then go about taking that functional derivative and turning it into the gradient of the probability? Is there a reference you would recommend or a method that you'd use. You explained the first part very clearly, but I am not really familiar with functional derivatives (especially of random variables).

Comment: I'm sorry I hadn't really looked at the problem in any detail. What it seems like you want is to just derive Fokker-Planck, and you'll be pleased to find that much more straightforward derivations abound (and you should find plenty on this website, too). The result of Eq. (3) in the paper looks to me like just the Fokker-Planck form of (1a), (1b), so a plug and play of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation.